# Style UITableViewCell inside UIScrollView/UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

### Overview

I've added a UITableView inside a UIScrollView using the storyboard.

My simple goal is to style the UITableViewCell's inside this table view.

### Code

Currently, I have added a UITableView property to the view controller and added the outlet in the storyboard.

```
@interface NWDetailViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,
    UITableViewDataSource> {
  IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
  ...
  IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
  IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tableViewHeightConstraint;
}
```

Created a custom UITableViewCell (NWLocationTableViewCell), added a property and connected the outlet in the storyboard:

```
@interface NWLocationTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
  IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
}
```

And this is how i'm trying to populate the cell in my Controller:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)thisTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"LocationCell";

  // Same with both tableView and thisTableView
  NWLocationTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[NWLocationTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                    reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  }


  [cell.titleLabel setText:@"test"];

  // or

  UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2112];
  [label setText:@"test"];

  NSLog(@"%@, %@", cell.contentView.subviews, cell.class);

  return cell;
}
```

But both methods yield nothing, hence I can't style it. Adding any static objects (UIButton for example) also don't show up.

The logs show: `"(), NWLocationTableViewCell"`

Comment: Do you get any errors? How do you know that you're not getting a cell?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this will help, but try taking your outlets out of the braces.  Declare them as properties underneath your braces and before `@end`, such as `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;`

Comment: @rdelmar No errors,  nil  indicates no cell

Comment: @gsean tried both ways but thank you

Comment: Do you mean nil in your logs? That means no titleLabel and no label, not necessarily no cell. You should just log cell. If I remember correctly, you get an error if cellFroRowAtIndexPath returns no cell.

Comment: Sorry you're quite right,  what I've shown doesn't illustrate the issue, setting the text value of the label retrieved by either method yields no result

Comment: To track down the problem, it would be good to try logging a couple of things to see what you get. Log cell.class to make sure its class is correct and cell.contentView.subviews to see what subviews there are.

Comment: @rdelmar Have added some logging, nothing seems to be showing up, what would this indicated?

Comment: I'm not sure how you could get that log -- you're returning the correct class of cell, but the label doesn't seem to be there. How did you add the label? In the storyboard? Also do a log of cell.titleLabel to what it returns. Did you register the class (you shouldn't if the cell was made in the storyboard)?

Answer (score 0):

Its a naming problem.

in your method header you pass `thisTableView` as the tableView to use, but then you call `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier];` to get a cell. It should generate an error, but probably there is another variable by that name, or a property? Anyways, if thats your verbatim code, theres your error.

Comment: Yes, tableView is a property referenced by the outlet, but same situation occurs when using thisTableView also

Comment: @ThomSeddon - so would you mind altering your question so others wont fall for the same trap as i did?

Comment: yeah, i meant fix the code, not add a comment. i did it for you. youre welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately you're solution isn't actually a fix and i'm not sure it's necessarily more correct, hence why I used a comment.

Comment: it is a fix in that it does eliminate an error that is only obscured by a bad naming convention (i.e. namimg a tableView `tableView`). also it is necessarily more correct in that in the delegate-method you should use the tableView-object that is passed by the tableview to the delegate, and NOT some class variable/property/whatever. Youre still free to delete my edit if you feel like it.